# What is ellipsis operator in c

Tags: c, function, ellipsis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's does … mean in an argument list in C ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124265/whats-does-mean-in-an-argument-list-in-c)

```
 function fun1(...)
    {
    }
```

Please tell me about what is the use and how to use ellipsis operator in c.
Thanks,

Comment: A good link for you: [here](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/how-to-use-variable-argument-lists-va_list/)

Answer (score 29):

An ellipsis is used to represent a variable number of parameters to a function. For example:

```
void format(const char* fmt, ...)
```

The above function in C could then be called with different types and numbers of parameters such as:

```
format("%d-%d-%d", 2010, 9, 25);
```

and

```
format("product: %s, price: %f", "HDD", 450.90);
```

[C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) introduced [Variadic macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro) which also makes use of ellipsis.