# Pass a wxString into a printf-style varargs function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I am learning to code in C using K&R II.  I am tired of console apps and decided to get into a GUI environment.  Decided to use Code Blocks and wxWidgets.  All is installed properly and working.  [Windows 7 x86, Code Blocks 13.12, wxWidgets 3.0.0]

I am following the [Tutorials on WxWidgets](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=WxSmith_tutorials). I am in Tutorial 9. I have it working, finally; there are mistakes in the instructions.

I modified my app to have 2 text boxes and a button vs one text box for the output and one combo box for the input.

Visual C++ environment is totally foreign to me.

For the Button click I would like instead of printing, `"O brave new world!\n"`,
I would like to read what has been entered in `textbox1` and print it into `textbox2`.

The instruction:

```
wxString Text = TextCtrl1->GetValue();
```

gets the string that has been entered in textbox1

I have a call to the function

```
void printg(char *fmt, ...);
```

I need to know how/what to change the `...` argument to so it will passes the `wxString Text` in the form of an array, I think, to that printg function.  I am sure the first thing I need to do is change the Text string to an array, or some way to pass the string itself.

UPDATE 01/08/13 3:35 PM

I cut the code from the Textbox Enter event and pasted it into the ButtonClick event and now I can get the text in Box one to box two.

Now, I need a way to pass the text from textbox 1 to one of my C files, do whatever the exercise is about and pass it back to the click event to be passed to the printg function.

NOTE: I see confusion about printg.  I think it is a feature of wxWidgets that lets you print back to a GUI form rather than a console as printf does.  It works.

I would put the code on here, but I do not know how.  Tried before and get a message about it not being formatted properly.

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: I think you mean `printf` not `printg`

Comment: The "..." is  the ellipsis operator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792761/what-is-ellipsis-operator-in-c.

Comment: If you want to put it in another text box, why would you want to use `printf` (assuming you meant that with `printg`)?

Comment: down voters, at least indicate why.  And mis-spelling a word would probably be a stretch considering the field we are in, don't you think?

Answer (score 3):

`Text.ToUTF8().data()` gives you `const char *`

Also if you only want `char*` instead of `const char *` you can use `const_cast<char *>(Text.ToUTF8().data())`

Answer (score 2):

The most convenient thing to do is to use wx equivalents of standard functions, i.e. `wxPrintf()` in this case, because they allow you to pass `wxString` (and also `std::string`, `std::wstring`, `char*` and `wchar_t*`) objects directly, without doing anything special. So you could simply write

```
wxString s = ...;
wxPrintf("My string is %s\n", s);
```

OTOH using either `printf()` or `wxPrintf()` is generally not very useful in GUI applications, you probably want [wxLogMessage()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__log.html#ga249358701f3c2d410088ddf7a61d8564) or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, I Searched the "wx equivalents of standard functions" and found the string class reference page where I will spend some time trying to learn more.  I'd vote this up but I do not have enough points on this site.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string:  `char *str = {"this is my string"};`

Then you can use *printf()* like this:

`printf("%s\n", str);`

Note, there is no *printg()* in the C language.  And the prototype of the *printf()* statement allows for multiple arguments to be passed as long as there is a format specifier for each argument.  For example, this shows 3 format specifiers, and three arguments:

```
printf("%s %d %f\n", str, 10, 13.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "..." argument is called the ellipse argument.  It's covered in the K&R book, section 7.3 (in my edition anyway).  It can have 0 or more arguments in it, as described by the *fmt argument.

If you already have a string ready, just call it like this:

```
printf("%s",str);
```