# How to work with a variable number of variables in C?

Tags: c, operators, stdio

So I was pondering about this problem in C using only `stdio.h` -

I have to write a program that reads an integer `p` and then reads `p` integers. Now I have to use these `p` integers and perform another operation on them to get a final answer, which my main program will return.

The problem is I don't know how to perform an operation on a variable number of integers. I tried using pointers but they don't seem to work.

Can anyone help please?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i, p, n;
        scanf ("%d", &p);
        for (n=0; n<p; n++){
            int a;
            scanf ("%d", &a);
            int *k=&a;
        }
        for (n=0; n<p; n++){
            int a=*k;
            if (a==0)
                i=0;
            else i=1;
        }
    return i;
}
```

What I want to do here is to read a certain integer `p`, then read `p` integers `a`, and if at least one of these `a`s is `0`, my answer is `0`. Otherwise it's `1`.

But the compiler says `*k` is not defined for the second for loop. What should I do?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: "I tried using pointers but they don't seem to work"--can you post this attempt? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: No it's not homework. It's not really a specific problem or anything, and anyway I am a physics major, and code for fun.

Comment: Yes, I could show you the program I wrote, but give me some time. I will have to rewrite it, since I deleted it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792761/what-is-ellipsis-operator-in-c

Comment: It has been edited now.

Comment: Are you aware of dynamic allocation?  Variable sized arrays? 2D arrays? 2D organsiation within a 1D array?

Comment: No I am not. But that's exactly what I am asking about. How do we make variable sized arrays? I know there's something called vectors in C++ which can do the job, but it's not present in C.

Comment: You probably need an array — are you using C99 or later, or are you stuck with C90?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a fixed number of variables. Like

```
int p, a, ans=1;
scanf("%d", &p); //read number

for(int r=0; r<p; ++r)
{
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if(a==0)
    {
        ans=0;
        break;
    }
}   
printf("\nAnswer is: %d", ans);
```

`ans` variable holds the answer. First you read the number of `int`s into `p` and then read `p` number of `int`s using a loop.

During each iteration of the loop, you read into the same variable `a`. You just need to know if at least a single input is zero.

`ans` is initially set to `1` and is changed to `0` only if a zero is input. If zero is input, the control exits the loop immediately because of the `break` statement.

You may want to check the return value of `scanf()` and other error checking.

Various ways to use an unknown number of variables is mentioned in the comments.

If you can use C99, [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99) are allowed. Like

```
int p;
scanf("%d", &p);
int arr[p];
```

If dynamic memory allocation is used, you could use `malloc()` or `calloc()` which are in `stdlib.h`.

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

---

And the pointer `k` in

```
    for (n=0; n<p; n++){
        int a;
        scanf ("%d", &a);
        int *k=&a;
    }
    for (n=0; n<p; n++){
        int a=*k;
        if (a==0)
            i=0;
        else i=1;
    }
```

is a local variable of the first loop and is hence visible only to that loop and is invisible to the second loop. `k`'s scope is limited to the first loop. See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope).

If you want a variable to be visible in both the loops, declare it outside both.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know there was something called break. This does answer my question .

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I'll help you understand the compiler error you talked about:

> k is not defined for the second for loop

```
// some code

for (n=0; n<p; n++){
    int a;
    scanf ("%d", &a);
    int *k=&a;   // Definition of k is here, and is restricted to this block, 
}
for (n=0; n<p; n++){
    int a=*k;   // Its undefined here
    if (a==0)
       i=0;
    else i=1;
}
// some code
```

Explanation: Read the comment in the code. What I meant by block is the code between the upper '{' and lower '}'. Beyond these, anywhere in code, k is undefined. Hence in second loop, the k is undefined.
You should change your `main()` function to:

```
int main() 
{
    int i, p, n, k = 0;
    scanf ("%d", &p);
    for (n=0; n<p; n++) {
        int a;
        scanf ("%d", &a);
        int *k=&a;
    }
    for (n=0; n<p; n++) {
        int a=*k;
        if (a==0)
            i=0;
        else 
            i=1;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Now to address your next issue, I guess you might want to study [variadic functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Functions.html) in C. I may be wrong in understanding your problem statement, but my take on it is that you are willing to pass multiple arguments to a function. For example,

At some time, you want to call `function` as:

```
function(Count_args, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

and sometimes as:

```
function(Count_args, 10);
```

If I am right, you might want to take a look at [this example](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Example.html#Variadic-Example) on the same reference I cited above. For making your life easier, I am adding the same code here:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
add_em_up (int count,...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int i, sum;

    va_start (ap, count);         /* Initialize the argument list. */

    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    sum += va_arg (ap, int);    /* Get the next argument value. */

    va_end (ap);                  /* Clean up. */
    return sum;
}

int
main (void)
{
    /* This call prints 16. */
    printf ("%d\n", add_em_up (3, 5, 5, 6));

    /* This call prints 55. */
    printf ("%d\n", add_em_up (10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));

    return 0;
}
```

If you are willing to know that latest standard says about having variable arguments to a function, refer C11, section [7.16 Variable arguments](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16) , it does help!

Comment: Thank you, that did really help a lot. I will certainly take a look at everything you mentioned.