# Arguments in C error

Tags: c, cpputest

I am unit testing a function which has arguments like;

```
extern int32_t
fabl_fmtstr_fprint (FILE *op UNUSED, const char *format, ...){}
```

I am not sure what the argument "..." is for. I am getting compile time error for it.

```
error: declaration of C function 'int32_t fabl_fmtstr_fprint(FILE*, const char*, int)' 
conflicts with
previous declaration 'int32_t fabl_fmtstr_fprint(FILE*, const char*, ...)' here
```

Could anybody explain me the reason? And I am using CppUTest(C++) for unittesting.

I have declared the funtion being FAKE as,

```
FAKE_VALUE_FUNC(int32_t, fabl_fmtstr_fprint, FILE* ,const char *, int);
```

In this case its asking for the missing "..." argument.

Comment: The error message says that you have provided two different declarations for this function. Decide which one is wrong and fix it.  (Possibly one is an implicit declaration, if you called the function before having its prototype in scope, but that should also have given a warning or an error)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: An implicit declaration would not have a return type of `int32_t`.

Comment: @KeithThompson the standard doesn't require diagnostics to make sense ;) But you're probably right and there is actually a bogus prototype.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ... mean in an argument list in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124265/what-does-mean-in-an-argument-list-in-c)

Comment: Is your question about what's causing the error or what the `...` means?

Comment: Is this C or C++? The question says C++, but you tagged it C.

Comment: https://meekrosoft.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/fake-function-framework-request-for-comments/ - see the comments section.